# Conditional probability of (A or B | C)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have searched for Conditional probability of (A or B | C), and found the reverse on the website:

$$p(C|A \cup B) =\frac{p(C(A \cup B))}{p(A \cup B)}=\frac{p(CA) + p(CB) - p(CAB)}{p(A) + p(B) - p(AB)}=$$

$$=\frac{p(C|A)p(A) + p(C|B)p(B) - p(C|AB)p(AB)}{p(A) + p(B) - p(AB)}$$

so.. what if I want p(A∪B | C) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}P(A\cup B\mid C) &= \frac{P((A\cup B)\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&= \frac{P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C) - P((A\cap B)\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&= P(A\mid C) +P(B\mid C)-P((A\cap B)\mid C).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Bayes' Theorem applied to the events $A\cup B$ and $C$ asserts$$ P(A \cup B\mid C )=\frac{P(C\mid A \cup B)P(A \cup B)}{P(C)}. $$

Answer (score 0):

You have,

$$
P(C \mid A \cup B) = \frac{P(C \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)}
$$
which is just the product rule of probability. Similarly,

$$
P(A \cup B \mid C) = \frac{P(C \cap (A \cup B))}{P(C)}.
$$

The rest of the steps are similar to what you have already shown.